# How to add website links to a random image generator

Tags: javascript, html

i have this code and want to know how to add website links to the images, once the random image is generated i want the image can be clicked to go to a predetermined list of websites, it's a really beginner question since i don't really understand javascript functions.

Thank you.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
//preload the six images first
var face0=new Image()
face0.src="d1.gif"
var face1=new Image()
face1.src="d2.gif"
var face2=new Image()
face2.src="d3.gif"
var face3=new Image()
face3.src="d4.gif"
var face4=new Image()
face4.src="d5.gif"
var face5=new Image()
face5.src="d6.gif"
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="d1.gif" name="mydice">
<form>
<input type="button" value="Throw dice!" onClick="throwdice()">
</form>
<script>
function throwdice(){
    //create a random integer between 0 and 5
    var randomdice=Math.round(Math.random()*5)
    document.images["mydice"].src=eval("face"+randomdice+".src")
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, can you please first confirm on which path your images are?

Comment: I'm using pictures hosted in Imgur, something like this: https://i.imgur.com/56TJ9Oc.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can make it with JavaScript

```js
    function getRandom(){
var RandomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
var link =["Link1","Link2","Link3","Link4","Link5","Link6"]
var resultDiv = document.getElementById('result');
resultDiv.innerHTML = '<a href="link.com"><img src="dice' + RandomNumber1 + '.png"></a>';
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Throw Dices" onClick="getRandom()">
    <div id="result">
        <img src="d1.gif" name="mydice">
    </div>
```

Comment: <a href="link.com"><img src="d1.gif" name="mydice"></a>
I have to declare every single image with that, right?
using a <a href="random.com"> </a>

Comment: Yes :) Is that what you want? You can put it just one time and every time you throw the dice it will link the image inside to the link

Comment: I want to declare different links for each of the images, so when a determined face of the dice shows then i can click and go to that site, i tried but it failed.

Comment: I'm giving up, i can't run it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the (dangerous) [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function nor do you need to pre-load the images for this.

Just place all your image links (`d1.gif`, `d2.gif`, etc) in an array and similarly, place all the links you want the images to respectively link to in another array.

In your HTML, wrap the `<img>` element in an anchor tag `<a>` and now you can just update the anchor tag's `href` value as well as the img `src` value whenever the button is clicked.

Also, you don't need a `form` for the button. Just create the button as a separate element and add the click event listener to that button.

---

Check and run the following Code Snippet for a practical example of the above approach:

```js
//get the anchor tag that has the image and the button
const image = document.querySelector('a');
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');


//assign the src links and href links to arrays
const links = ["someLink1", "someLink2","someLink3","someLink4","someLink5","someLink6"]
const images = ["d1.gif","d2.gif","d3.gif","d4.gif","d5.gif","d6.gif"]

//update the src link and href link
function throwdice(){
    const randomIndex = Math.round(Math.random()*5);
    image.href= links[randomIndex];
    image.firstChild.src= images[randomIndex];
}

//run the function when the button is clicked
btn.addEventListener('click', throwdice)
```

```html
<h3>Right-click the image and inspect it to see the anchor tag link and the img src link change whenever the button is clicked</h3>

<a href="#1"><img src="d1.gif" name="mydice"></a>
<button id="btn">Throw dice!</button>
```

Comment: I works perfectly, but i cannot run it in my blog, i'm using blogger.

Comment: "In your HTML, wrap the <img> element in an anchor tag <a> and now you can just update the anchor tag's href value as well as the img src value whenever the button is clicked."

I don't understand that, also my english is pretty bad.